# put < as value in android xml file

Tags: android, xml

how can i do this in andoroid xml file without error?

```
<Key android:keyLabel="<" />
```

i tried `"\<"` but is doesn't work too!
any help appreciated!

Comment: Try "&lt;"... may be this will work...

Comment: You can't put "<" in an XML attribute value without error, because "<" in an XML attribute value is an error by definition. It needs to be escaped as `&lt;`

Answer (score 5):

What about:

```
<Key android:keyLabel="&lt;" />
```

see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1091953/180100)